# PHP: preg_replace() characters and make exceptions

Tags: php, html, regex

I need an `if()` function to do this:

`preg_replace()` letters (`a`, `b`, `c`, etc.) except for those wrapped in tags (`<p>`, `<b>`, `<span>`, etc.) and exclude the letters if they are part of a certain word.

```
$string = "<p>replace everything inside tags <b>only</b> </p>exception";  
$patterns = array();  
$patterns[0] = '/e/';  
$patterns[1] = '/b/';  
$patterns[2] = '/s/';  
$replacements = array();  
$replacements[2] = '-e-';  
$replacements[1] = '-b-';  
$replacements[0] = '-s-';  
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

I want "`<p>`", "`<b>`" and the word "exception" to remain unaltered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost always a bad idea to try to do in regex. You should try to use an HTML parser instead:

[Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)